# How to get forward-slash separated path from java.nio.file.Path on regardless of the environment in Java

Tags: java, windows

I want to get String separated by forward-slash `/` from `java.nio.file.Path`.
However, `toString` uses backward-slash `\` as a separator on Windows machines.

Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/path-tostring-method-in-java-with-examples/

Is there good solutions?
Candidates that I have are following. But I don't think they are good ideas.

- replace `File.pathSeparator` by `/`
- join `Path.iterator()` by `/`

Sharing context, I want to use `org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.IgnoreNode`.
`checkIgnored` only has poor interface that accepts `String` rather than `Path` and it seems to works with only paths separated by `/`.

Comment: Maybe method [toURI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri--), in interface `java.nio.file.Path`, since a URI only has forward slashes as path separators.

Comment: Why are you using the Path class at all, when git entries are not filesystem paths?

Comment: @Abra
Thank you for your suggestion. `toUri` returns absolute URI. Unfortunately, I want a relative path.

@VGR
I'm sorry but I don't understand what you ask.
I handle file paths over `Path` to avoid environment dependent behavior.
And code that uses Jgit is just a small part of the project I participate.
I don't want to use String for path only for this reason.
Is this help for your question?

Comment: I might understand @VGR 's question.
`Path` interface comes from `Files.newDirectoryStream`.

Comment: One of the primary purposes of Path is to represent a platform dependent path.  Using Path is fundamentally environment dependent.  Git entries may look like filesystem paths, but they are not filesystem paths.  The Path class should not be used to represent something which is not a filesystem path.

Comment: Thank you for your friendly description. I didn't understand that git entries are not filesystem path. Now I understand that is why `checkIgnored` doesn't accept Path class.
In my case, I want to implement project specific ignore file that have same syntax with `.gitignore`. So I want to pass filesystem paths to `checkIgnored` rather than git entries.

Comment: How about you get your path and replace the \ with a / in the string afterwards?

Comment: @Sascha
Is it work better than replacing `File.pathSeparator` with `/`? It seems to fail if `\\` exists in file name or directory name (on Unix-like system).

Comment: @Seiya You can do it for Windows only. Simply check before if File.separatorChar == '\\'

Comment: @Sascha
I see. Then it works same as `path.toString().replace(File.separatorChar, '/')` I wrote in the question. I'm sorry that it is not clear.

Comment: @Seiya Yes, it's just preventing the String-"no op". 
I found this usage of IgnoreNode where I don't see any path conversion: https://www.javatips.net/api/perconik-master/sk.stuba.fiit.perconik.eclipse/src/sk/stuba/fiit/perconik/eclipse/jgit/lib/GitRepositories.java